# Authentication Token

Tags: siesta-swift

I'm trying to setup a simple iOS example to better understand Siesta.  My REST api requires an access token to accompany each request. So (1) at the start of the app and (2) anytime I retrieve a HTTP 401 I need to request an access token and then put that in all future Authorization headers.

Working off this example from the documentation, I assume the line containing `showLoginScreen` is where I need to make a call to my `authenticationResource` to retrieve the token BUT how do I make the failed call immediately after (and not infinite loop of course)? Thank you.

```
let authURL = authenticationResource.url

configure({ url in url != authURL }, description: "catch auth failures") {
  $0.config.beforeStartingRequest { _, req in  // For all resources except auth:
    req.onFailure { error in                     // If a request fails...
      if error.httpStatusCode == 401 {         // ...with a 401...
        showLoginScreen()                      // ...then prompt the user to log in
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “how do I make the failed call immediately after?” Are you asking about how to call authenticationResource, or about how to reattempt the call that produced the 401 if authentication succeeds?

Comment: Yes, how do I reattempt the call. Right now I do an call at the beginning of the view controller to get the token but I know that's wrong because I made need to get a token again (timeout?) while in the same view. So the logic would be to always check if I have a token before a rest call, get the token and reattempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked the question, the docs have been updated with [an example that answers it](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/configuration/#decorating-requests-via-configuration).

The crux of it is to use [`decorateRequests(…)`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Structs/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/swift/Method/decorateRequests(with:)) and [`Request.chained(…)`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Protocols/Request.html#//apple_ref/swift/Method/chained(whenCompleted:)) to wrap all your service’s requests so that they automatically attempt to refresh the token before returning a response.

Here is the code from that example:

```
authToken: String??

init() {
  ...
  configure("**", description: "auth token") {
    if let authToken = self.authToken {
      $0.headers["X-Auth-Token"] = authToken         // Set the token header from a var that we can update
    }
    $0.decorateRequests {
      self.refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: $1)
    }
  }
}

// Refactor away this pyramid of doom however you see fit
func refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: Request) -> Request {
  return request.chained {
    guard case .failure(let error) = $0.response,  // Did request fail…
      error.httpStatusCode == 401 else {           // …because of expired token?
        return .useThisResponse                    // If not, use the response we got.
    }

    return .passTo(
      self.createAuthToken().chained {             // If so, first request a new token, then:
        if case .failure = $0.response {           // If token request failed…
          return .useThisResponse                  // …report that error.
        } else {
          return .passTo(request.repeated())       // We have a new token! Repeat the original request.
        }
      }
    )
  }
}

func createAuthToken() -> Request {
  return tokenCreationResource
    .request(.post, json: userAuthData())
    .onSuccess {
      self.authToken = $0.jsonDict["token"] as? String  // Store the new token, then…
      self.invalidateConfiguration()                    // …make future requests use it
    }
  }
}
```